# How to workout with more than one loop in one iMacros script?

Tags: javascript, imacros, webautomation

I hope that everyone will be in perfect health.I am trying to add two for loops in my iMacros script but only the first loop works and then stops the script and doesn't move forward to the 2nd loop and ends with the following error as :

> TypeError: a is undefined, line 15 (Error code: -991)

**The Script :**

```
var test;
test ="CODE:";
test +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES "+" \n";
test +="TAB T=1"+" \n";
test +="URL GOTO=http://clicksandearns.com/index.php?tp=paidclicks "+" \n";

iimPlay(test);


var a_list = window.content.document.getElementsByTagName("a");

X = 1;
for (var i = 0, len = a_list.length; i <= len; i++) {
    var a = a_list[i];
    if (a.href.indexOf("tp=visit") > -1) {
var test;
test ="CODE:";
test +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES "+" \n";
test +="' AD FIRST "+X+" \n";
test +="TAB OPEN "+" \n";
test +="TAB T=2"+" \n";
test +="URL GOTO="+a.href+" \n";
test +="WAIT SECONDS=13 "+" \n";
test +="FRAME NAME=visit "+" \n";
test +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:ss ATTR=TYPE:Submit&&NAME:submit&&VALUE:Continue<SP>for<SP>Credit "+" \n";
test +="WAIT SECONDS=2 "+" \n";
test +="TAB CLOSE"+" \n";


iimPlay(test);
X++;
    } 

    }

var test;
test ="CODE:";
test +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES "+" \n";
test +="TAB T=1"+" \n";
test +="URL GOTO=http://clicksandearns.com/index.php?tp=paidclicks&st=&s=&start=35 "+" \n";

iimPlay(test);


var a_list = window.content.document.getElementsByTagName("a");

X = 1;
for (var i = 0, len = a_list.length; i <= len; i++) {
    var a = a_list[i];
    if (a.href.indexOf("tp=visit") > -1) {
var test;
test ="CODE:";
test +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES "+" \n";
test +="' AD LAST "+X+" \n";
test +="TAB OPEN "+" \n";
test +="TAB T=2"+" \n";
test +="URL GOTO="+a.href+" \n";
test +="WAIT SECONDS=13 "+" \n";
test +="FRAME NAME=visit "+" \n";
test +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:ss ATTR=TYPE:Submit&&NAME:submit&&VALUE:Continue<SP>for<SP>Credit "+" \n";
test +="WAIT SECONDS=2 "+" \n";
test +="TAB CLOSE"+" \n";


iimPlay(test);
X++;
    } 

    }
```

Looking forward if anyone can help me out with this issue or to workout with this issue some another alternate way.Will be grateful for the help..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your for loops:

`for (var i = 0, len = a_list.length; i <= len; i++) {`

It should be replaced with:

`for (var i = 0, len = a_list.length; i < len; i++) {`

There is no items with index `len` - only `len-1`... 
As a result you get an exception when trying to read `href` property of `undefined`

Comment: Ahaa...You mean I can't use `<=` as there is no items with index `len` just only `len-1` that it always has to be `1` minimum or less than right???

Comment: Can you explain it little bit more perfectly with an example so it will be nice please?

Comment: for example if you have 2 items - their indices would be `[0,1]`. but when you will use `<=` in for condition you will iterate over indices `[0,1,2]`. if you use `<` you will iterate over items with index strictly less than 2 - `[0,1]`, and it would be exactly what you need.